# In Python, how do I change one column of a dataframe based on another?

Tags: python, dataframe

In a dataframe with columns *x* and *y*, how would I write code so that if a row has an *x* string but a 'Not assigned' *y* string (the *y* column contains the string "Not assigned"), then the *y* string will be the same as the *x* string?
(Overwriting the "Not assigned" string in column *y* with the contents of column *x*)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.iterrows()` checking the values of the columns conditionally as you iterate.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [6, "Not Assigned", 8]})

for index, value in df.iterrows():
  if value['y'] == 'Not Assigned':
    df['y'][index] = df['x'][index]
```

Output:

```
    x   y
0   1   6
1   2   2
2   3   8
```

Comment: there are vectorized solutions that would be much more efficient than looping

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['y']=='Not assigned', 'y'] = df.loc[df['y']=='Not assigned', 'x']
```

would do it

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.